# How to remove boilerplate from Razor View

Tags: c#, razor, boilerplate

I have a set of feature-rich `HTML Helper` functions that all of my views use.

However, there is one line of boilerplate that I must include in almost every view:

```
@{
    var metaData = ModelMetadataProviders
        .Current
        .GetMetadataForType(null, Model.GetType());
}
```

I pass this value to my helpers with a call like this:

```
@j6h.OutputForEdit(metaData, Html, account => account.User)
```

Is there a way to move the boiler-plate code out of the view?

I've considered trying to add the code to `_ViewStart.cshtml` or `_ViewStart.cs`, but I don't have the `Model` variable available at that spot.

I know I could make a change the boilerplate through a function call:

```
var metaData = GetMetaDataForModel(Model);
```

Any hints on how I can remove the boiler plate code all together?